# How to visualize JSON data as tree diagrams using D3.js?

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

I want to visualize huge nested JSON objects as tree diagrams using D3.js.
All example are using JSON files which contain their hierarchy as explicit information, for example here the *children* attribute:

```
{
   "name":"Alex",
   "children":[
      {
         "name":"Josh",
         "children":[
            {
               "name":"Joelle"
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "name":"David",
         "children":[
            {
               "name":"Lina"
            },
            {
               "name":"Martha"
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "name":"Lara",
         "children":[
            
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

In the JSON data I want to visualize, there are many different attributes containing arrays of *child-objects*.

```
{
   "fruit":"Apple",
   "vitamins":[
      {
         "name":"Vitamin C",
         "consistsOf":[
            {
               "id":"H",
               "name":"Hydrogen",
               "colors":[
                  {
                     "name":"colorless"
                  }
               ]
            },
            {
               "id":"O",
               "name":"Oxygen",
               "colors":[
                  {
                     "name":"colorless"
                  },
                  {
                     "name":"blue"
                  }
               ]
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "name":"Vitamin D",
         "consistsOf":[
            {
               "id":"H",
               "name":"Hydrogen",
               "colors":[
                  {
                     "name":"colorless"
                  }
               ]
            },
            {
               "id":"O",
               "name":"Oxygen",
               "colors":[
                  {
                     "name":"colorless"
                  },
                  {
                     "name":"blue"
                  }
               ]
            },
            {
               "id":"C",
               "name":"Carbon",
               "colors":[
                  {
                     "name":"black"
                  },
                  {
                     "name":"grey"
                  }
               ]
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

Doesn't the JSON language implicitly show relationships between the objects, so that a tree can be drawn by D3.js? How do I achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

All what you have to do is to create your page HTML, like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <title> Tree Example</title>

    <style>

    .node circle {
      fill: #fff;
      stroke: steelblue;
      stroke-width: 3px;
    }

    .node text { font: 12px sans-serif; }

    .link {
      fill: none;
      stroke: #ccc;
      stroke-width: 2px;
    }
    
    </style>

  </head>

  <body>

<!-- load the d3.js library --> 
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.17/d3.min.js"></script>
    
<script>

// ************** Generate the tree diagram  *****************
var margin = {top: 20, right: 120, bottom: 20, left: 120},
    width = 960 - margin.right - margin.left,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;
    
var i = 0;

var tree = d3.layout.tree()
    .size([height, width]);

var diagonal = d3.svg.diagonal()
    .projection(function(d) { return [d.y, d.x]; });

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.right + margin.left)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

// load the external data
d3.json("YourJsonFile.json", function(error, treeData) {
  root = treeData[0];
  update(root);
});

function update(source) {

  // Compute the new tree layout.
  var nodes = tree.nodes(root).reverse(),
      links = tree.links(nodes);

  // Normalize for fixed-depth.
  nodes.forEach(function(d) { d.y = d.depth * 180; });

  // Declare the nodes…
  var node = svg.selectAll("g.node")
      .data(nodes, function(d) { return d.id || (d.id = ++i); });

  // Enter the nodes.
  var nodeEnter = node.enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "node")
      .attr("transform", function(d) { 
          return "translate(" + d.y + "," + d.x + ")"; });

  nodeEnter.append("circle")
      .attr("r", 10)
      .style("fill", "#fff");

  nodeEnter.append("text")
      .attr("x", function(d) { 
          return d.children || d._children ? -13 : 13; })
      .attr("dy", ".35em")
      .attr("text-anchor", function(d) { 
          return d.children || d._children ? "end" : "start"; })
      .text(function(d) { return d.name; })
      .style("fill-opacity", 1);

  // Declare the links…
  var link = svg.selectAll("path.link")
      .data(links, function(d) { return d.target.id; });

  // Enter the links.
  link.enter().insert("path", "g")
      .attr("class", "link")
      .attr("d", diagonal);

}

</script>
    
  </body>
</html>
```

Wish that it could help!

Comment: replace the load the d3.js library by this `<script src="//d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>` and don't forget to much the html file with your json file

Comment: sorry, deleted my last comment.
I get the following error "TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'i.depth=0')" on line 57, so treeData[0] seems to be empty, treeData contains the JSON object as expected

Comment: after changing to d3.v3.min.js, it shows no errors but only one circle on the page

Comment: maybe you have to check the structure of your json data!  can you post a screenshot please

Comment: for testing I used exact the same data as posted here, saved in a JSON file. I also validated it using jsonlint.com

Comment: I couldn't get this to work with the JSON provided above.  I was able to generate a diagram from nested JSON data using this page: https://codepen.io/nvelden/pen/LYmveWz?editors=1111 (but need to learn D3 to understand how it works).  Would be great if the true answer showed the resulting diagram!